# Disable back button when Soft Keyboard pops up, Android

Tags: java, android

I shifted the whole layout of my page by 250 when user inputs on the two EditText fields, and I need to shit it back when the keyboard is dismissed, I used

public class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE 
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

            LoginActivity.rootView.setY(0);
            return true;    
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    return false;
}
```

}
And it works fine, but when I click the back button, the keyboard is also dismissed and the layout is not shifted back. Is there a way to disable the back button only when the soft keyboard is up?

Answer (score 1):

set a variable when soft keyboard is up ([how to check visibility of software keyboard in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)) and check it in your overridden `onBackPressed()` method. If keyboard is up, do nothing, otherwise call the super method.

private boolean isKeyboardUp;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(isKeyboardUp)
          //do nothing
        else
          super.onBackPressed();
    }
```